# window.self.close() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I opened a print window using `window.print()`. I tried using `window.self.close()`,
but I was unable to close that one. I am using Firefox. My idea was to close the window by itself if the user doesn't perform any action on it.

This is the code I am using for print window.

```
 $('.click-print-paybymail').live("click", function (e) {
    var amount = $('.amount-enclosed').val();
    var ccnum = $('.credit-card-account-number').val();

    var isAllow = true;
    if (!isValidCC(ccnum)) {
        isAllow = false;
    }
    if (!isValidAmount(amount)) {
        isAllow = false;
    }
    if (isAllow) {
        window.print();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not close the print dialog programmatically from javascript since it is not a browser window - its an operating system dialog.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply.so is there any alternative for this,as the main reason for  closing this window is,i got a session timeout window which pops up when the user leaves the screen  idle,but that event is not popping up when the print button is clicked on the page and the print modal is open.so i trying to find out a solution to close the print window.Any other alternative for my problem.