# Set a timer to a print window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we create a timer function for print window in jquery or javascript,My intention was to set a timer so that the the print window closes successfully by itself when the user doesnt perform any operation on it.

Comment: The browser's print dialog is an application-level, browser-specific thing, rather than under page-specific controls. I'm thinking it probably isn't possible to do what you're asking, but since I don't know for certain I won't put in an answer.

Comment: Furthermore, in some browsers the print dialog is modal, blocking access to anything else, while in others (Chrome, specifically) it opens as a regular browser tab.

Comment: In IE on an intranet you may still be able to use the activeX [scriptX](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/) from MeadCo

Comment: This is (more a less) a duplicate of two of your own recent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8673620/615754, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8719641/615754 - you've already accepted an answer that says it can't be done.